# How to I write a function in markdown with if and else options

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I been trying to find how to do this in markdown for a while. I can not find any documentation on this. If someone can help me out.

Thanks.

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRG8t.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a markdown cell

```
$$
\hat y
= 
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ if } \hat p < 0.5\\
1 \text{ if } \hat p \geqslant 0.5
\end{cases}
$$
```

This will create

[image: output]